# In C#, how to check whether a string contains an integer?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, integer, tryparse

I just want to know, whether a String variable **contains a parsable** positive integer value. I do NOT want to parse the value right now.

Currently I am doing:

```
int parsedId;
if (
    (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStringVariable) ||
    (!uint.TryParse(myStringVariable, out parsedId))
)
{//..show error message}
```

**This is ugly - How to be more concise?**

Note: I know about extension methods, but I wonder if there is something built-in.

Comment: Do you need to allow for negative numbers?

Comment: Keep the code you have, and live with the ugliness.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for spotting this. It's positive only in my case, clarified the question.

Comment: Change from `int.TryParse` to `uint.TryParse` to have strings that look like negative integers return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be **just no.**

Although there are many good other answers, they either just hide the uglyness (which I did not ask for) or introduce new problems (edge cases).

Comment: I guess the designers of C# could introduce some new syntactic sugar for this case where we don't care about the out variable. It could look like `int.TryParse(myStringVariable, out void)` or something. The compiler should then automatically introduce a "generated" local variable of the correct type, but it would not look ugly in code. Of course the generated variable would not be accessible (should have some "crazy" illegal name).

Answer (score 155):

You could use [char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58.aspx):

```
     bool isIntString = "your string".All(char.IsDigit)
```

Will return `true` if the string is a number

```
    bool containsInt = "your string".Any(char.IsDigit)
```

Will return `true` if the string contains a digit

Comment: If `str` is equal to `"iuhs,./hu3dwuh"`, then `str.Any(char.IsDigit)` will be true.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but 1. There's no static function on the `string` class called `Any` (presumably you meant for the string variable to be called `string`, but that's not possible); 2. If you're referring to the Linq extension method `Any`, you have to call it liks this: `s.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c))`; 3. I think he wants the *whole* string to be an integer, not just to contain a digit somewhere; otherwise it makes no sense for him to use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken Regarding your (2): No, since the signature and return type is correct, the expression `char.IsDigit` (a so-called method group) _can_ be converted to type `Func<char, bool>` through an implicit conversion, so that part is OK.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Good call. I always forget about that.

Comment: I upvoted but it would be nice if you could update your answer to be correct linq like Magnus suggested.

Comment: @TroySteven - He's wrong though? You don't have to use lambda syntax e.g `s.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x))` you can just pass `char.IsDigit` as a delegate, try it... https://dotnetfiddle.net/qS59c0 and the first example satisfies the 'whole string is an integer'

Answer (score 39):

Assuming you want to check that all characters in the string are digits, you could use the [Enumerable.All Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) with the [Char.IsDigit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx) as follows:

```
bool allCharactersInStringAreDigits = myStringVariable.All(char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: What if `myStringVariable` contains digit characters from many different "scripts" from all over the world, such as Hindu-Arabic numerals combined with western numerals?

Comment: In that case, "۲۲۲" will give true, but parsing it as an int will throw an exception.

Comment: If you wanted to check if any of the characters was numeric and not all of them, you could use - bool anyCharactersInStringAreDigits = myStringVariable.Any(char.IsDigit);

Answer (score 33):

Maybe this can help

```
string input = "hello123world";
bool isDigitPresent = input.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c));
```

answer from [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3de780d3-8fc0-41db-9bee-2fbfe6feebf1/possible-to-tell-if-a-string-contains-a-number?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: This is wrong. It will check whether some digits are present, but not whether the string as a whole does represent an integer value.

Comment: The requirements of the question are whether a string *Contains* parsable integer, not whether or not the entire string represents an number.

Answer (score 8):

You can check if string contains numbers only:

```
Regex.IsMatch(myStringVariable, @"^-?\d+$")
```

But number can be bigger than `Int32.MaxValue` or less than `Int32.MinValue` - you should keep that in mind.

Another option - create extension method and move ugly code there:

```
public static bool IsInteger(this string s)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
       return false;

   int i;
   return Int32.TryParse(s, out i);
}
```

That will make your code more clean:

```
if (myStringVariable.IsInteger())
    // ...
```

Comment: straight forward answer

Comment: Nice. I have enhanced your method to handle array of string. `public static bool IsInteger(this string[] str)
        {
            bool isInteger = false;
            if (str == null)
                return isInteger;

            foreach (var s in str)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                    return isInteger;

                int i;
                isInteger = Int32.TryParse(s, out i);
                if (isInteger == false)
                    return isInteger;
            }
            return isInteger;
        }`

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, didn't quite get your question. So something like this?

```
str.ToCharArray().Any(char.IsDigit);
```

Or does the value have to be an integer completely, without any additional strings?

```
if(str.ToCharArray().All(char.IsDigit(c));
```

Comment: What would your second answer return for `-----` ?

Comment: Just realised that ;)

Comment: @SBoss It should exactly be parsable as int, but I just want to now that, not the result of the parsing value.

Comment: Sorry Marcel, I should have read your question better. My second answer isn't really much prettier, but it's an alternative.

Comment: I get the first downvote for missing the point of the question, but since I modified my answer, why the second one?

Answer (score 4):

This work for me.

```
("your string goes here").All(char.IsDigit)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But however, this is a repetition of the answer @dtb already gave some years ago.

Answer (score 4):

```
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        bool isNumber = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(text[i]))
            {
                isNumber = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Text contains number.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Text doesn't contain number.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Or Linq:

```
        string text = Console.ReadLine();

        bool isNumberOccurance =text.Any(letter => char.IsDigit(letter));
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",isDigitPresent ? "Text contains number." : "Text doesn't contain number.");
        Console.ReadKey();
```