# Linq Not Numeric c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
Model.GetData.Where(p => p.Value != null).ToList();
```

I have values in my database like below,

**My Value Column:**

```
Null
Null
5
16
ExampleValue1
ExampleValue2
```

**p.value is string**

I only want to see "ExampleValue1" and "ExampleValue2".
How can i get datas not null and **not numeric** ?

Comment: what is the type of Value? Is it a `string`?

Comment: you can do that in SQL query field IS NOT NULL and ISNUMERIC(field)<>1

Comment: if it's a string you can look here for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251875/in-c-how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-an-integer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try on this..

```
int i;
var resultList = Model.GetData.Where(p => p.Value != null).ToList();
var finalResult= resultList.Where( t => !int.TryParse( t.Value , out i));
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps:

```
var BillingNumbers = Model.GetData
    .Where(p => p.Value != null && SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(p.Value) == 0);
```

Comment: +1 for using SqlFunctions.IsNumeric.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the results are of different types, you can query by type like this:
`var results = from item in collection where (item is String) select item;`

Example program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var collection = new List<Object>
    {
        5,
        1.5,
        null,
        "foo",
        "bar",
    };

    var results = from item in collection where (item is String) select item;

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: I maybe nitpicking here, but the requirement was not numeric and not null, not `item is String`. It could well be an IEnumerable or bool for what its worth

Comment: `Linq-To-Objects` and `Linq-To-Entities` are very different. You can always add `AsEnumerable` but that would read the whole result set from DB before applying the where condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely to this code :
result is just contains string

```
List<object> result = new List<object>();
        var MyList = new List<Object>{
                                523,
                                2.555,
                                null,
                                "ExampleValue1",
                                "ExampleValue2",
                            };
        MyList.ForEach(x =>
        {
            if (x != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Regex.Replace(x.ToString(), @"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$", string.Empty)))
                {
                    result.Add(x);
                }
            }
        });
```