# How to get string to contain only numbers, dashes, and space?

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am using regex to check if the string contains only numbers, dashes and spaces:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9- ]+$");

if(!regex.IsMatch(str))
```

How can I do this without regex?

Comment: You can use `String.Contains` to check for a character, and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251875/in-c-how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-an-integer) shows how to check for a digit.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable use of a RegEx. Why make things harder and slower?

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to iterate over the characters, and `char.IsDigit` to check for a digit.

```
bool invalid = myString.Any( x => x != ' ' && x != '-' && !char.IsDigit(x) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LINQ solution:

```
var allowedChars = "1234567890- ";
var str = "3275-235 23-325";

if (str.All(x => allowedChars.Contains(x))){
    Console.WriteLine("true");
}
```